Object 'sql_query_wrap.Oracle' not found
With dbplyr 2.1.1 I was using the next code
sql_translate_env.JDBCConnection <<- dbplyr:::sql_translation.Oracle
sql_select.JDBCConnection <<- dbplyr:::sql_query_select.Oracle
sql_subquery.JDBCConnection <<- dbplyr:::sql_query_wrap.Oracle

When updated to dbplyr 2.5.0 the last line no longer works, looking in the documentation I cant find the equivalent to sql_query_wrap.Oracle, and when looking in the git commits, seems like it was only removed

yes in dbplyr 2.5.0, the sql_query_wrap.Oracle function was removed.
you can use dbplyr::nest() as an alternatve
